# Loading OpenWebRTC-SDK in appcelerator Hyperloop through cocoa pods

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, appc-hyperloop, hyperloop

I'm trying to use OpenWebRTC in appcelerator with hyperloop and even it compiles and launches the app I can't access to the module.

This is my PodFile:

`platform :ios, '7.0'
target 'Hyperloop_Sample' do
    pod 'OpenWebRTC-SDK',  :git => 'https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-ios-sdk.git'
    pod 'JBChartView'
    pod 'GLCalendarView', '~> 1.2'
end`

and when I try to do `require('OpenWebRTC-SDK/OpenWebRTC')` the app fails with

> Couldn't find module OpenWebRTC-SDK/OpenWebRTC

If I try with other frameworks (i.e. Fabric and Crashlytics) it works properly.

Any clue?

Comment: link to JIRA issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20297

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify, that `OpenWebRTC-SDK/OpenWebRTC` is the right way to require the main class? You can validate that by checking the framework inside the Pods directory. It could also be a Hyperloop problems with parsing the C-based files included in the framework.

If you still experience problems, feel free to file a [JIRA-ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org) including your Podfile and a full stack trace. Thank you!